# Assigning Variables in a Java Calculator Program [Handling Assignments and Variables]

Tags: java, parsing, variables, calculator

I am currently in the middle of a Java calculator program and everything seems to be working correctly, but I want more functionality.

As of right now a user can enter a mathematic expression and the program will solve it. However, I'd like the program to assign numeric values to variables such as x, y, or z.

**Sample input/output could be:**

> Enter Expression: x=10/5
>
> ```
>                     => 2
> ```
>
> Enter Expression: x
>
> ```
>                     => 2
> ```

```
public class Calculator
{
   String expstring;
   int cursor;
   double x;
   double y;
   double z;


   public Calculator()
   {
      expstring = null;
      x = 0;
      y = 0;
      z = 0;
   }

   public Calculator(String instring)
   {
    expstring = instring;
    cursor = 0;
   }

   public void setExpression(String estring)
   {
      expstring = estring;
      cursor = 0;
   }

   public float evalExp()
   {
      if (expstring == null)
      {
         System.err.println("There is no expression to evaluate.");
         System.err.println("Call setExpression() before calling getResult().");
         return 0;
      }
      cursor = 0;
      float result = evalTerm();
      while (nextOperator('+') || nextOperator('-'))
      {
         char operator = getOperator();
         float term = evalTerm();
         if (operator == '+')
            result = result + term;
     if (operator == '-')
        result -= term;
         else
            System.err.println("Invalid operator: " + operator);
      }
      return result;
   }

   private float evalTerm()
   {
      float result = getOperand();
      while (nextOperator('*') || nextOperator('/'))
      {
         char operator = getOperator();
         float term = getOperand();
         if (operator == '*')
            result = result * term;
     if (operator == '/')
        result /= term;
         else
            break;
      }
      return result;
   }


   private float getOperand()
   {
      if (cursor >= expstring.length())
         return 0;
      String opstring = "";
      char nextchar = expstring.charAt(cursor);
      if (nextchar == '-')
      {
         opstring = opstring + '-';
         cursor++;
         nextchar = expstring.charAt(cursor);
      }
/**      if (nextchar == 'x')
      {
     x =    
      }
*/
      while (cursor < expstring.length() && !isOperator(nextchar))
      {
         opstring = opstring + nextchar;
         cursor++;
         if (cursor < expstring.length())
            nextchar = expstring.charAt(cursor);
      }
      return Float.parseFloat(opstring);
   }

   private char getOperator()
   {
      char operator = expstring.charAt(cursor);
      cursor++;
      return operator;
   }

   private boolean nextOperator(char op)
   {
      if (cursor < expstring.length() && expstring.charAt(cursor) == op)
         return true;
      else
         return false;
   }

   private boolean isOperator(char c)
   {
      String opset = "+*-/";
      return (opset.indexOf(c) >= 0);
   }
}
```

Here's what I've worked out so far, but I'm unsure how to implement it into code... The handling of variables and assignments can be embedded as special cases within the logical structure above, or it can be done in separate logic before/after the expression is evaluated. Your calculator class will need a field to store the value of each variable (x, y, and z). In an assignment, the first operand is a variable name and the first operator is =. The value of the expression to the right of = must be evaluated, and the value then can be stored in the field corresponding to the variable. If x, y, or z occurs in the expression to the right of =, its current value can be found in the corresponding field. The variables can be replaced with their values in the code that gets the next operand, or the variable values can be inserted in a separate pass through the expression before it is evaluated.

**Any help, inciteful links, or suggestions would be great!**

**I'm new on the programming scene and would like to learn.**

Answer (score 0):

instead of the line
 return Float.parseFloat(opstring);
you can verify if opstring begins with digit, something like

```
if (Character.isDigit(opstring.charAt(0)))
    return Float.parseFloat(opstring);
else
    return variables.get(opstring); // add additional test for null value!
```

you can declare variables container in your class as

```
final Map<String,Float> variables=new HashMap<String,Float>();
```

and initialize them when your parser encounters statements like  var = expr
    variable.put( name, value );

Comment: I would add all of this to the getOperand() method then?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answer would be useful to you as I could not understand the problem very well but here are few suggestions :

- To take a variable as input and print its value you can use a HashMap (java.util.HashMap) with String keys and Double values. This can be used to lookup values of variables by variable names. The same map can be used for complex expression such as x + y *z by parsing the expression and looking up the values.
- For parsing you can use methods of String class such as indexOf, substring() etc. Also consider using the StringTokenizer class which can take delimiters (+,-,*,/ in your case) and split an expression into tokens.